# Windows 7 workgroup remote shutdown

Tags: windows, remote

This is a strange, yet possibly easy question for many of you to answer but it's driving me crazy that I can't figure it out.

I have two machines on a local LAN on a workgroup. I recently learned that you can use the shutdown command to remotely shutdown a computer if you have the administrator credentials. Being curious I tried to remotely shutdown the PC in the next room over and contrary of what I thought, I was able to shutdown the PC.

Now this confuses me because I should only be allowed to do this if I have administrator credentials of that remote PC; or in the case of a domain, domain admin. At first I thought maybe that if guest account is enabled and is able to shutdown it could facilitate the need of administrator credentials. I checked computer management and local group policy but everything related to guest account is disabled, except for what file sharing enables.

I am also not a member of the Administrator group on that computer so besides the file sharing thing I don't know what could be allowing me this access.

Comment: Note that it is unusual, but entirely possible, to grant the "force shutdown from a remote system" right to non-administrators.

Answer (score 2):

You might be experiencing [Windows Pass-Through Authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102716). If your username and password are the same between two local PCs, passthrough authentication logs you right in and performs whatever action you tried without any prompts.

If you are not a local admin on the PC that you are sitting at, however the username and password exists on a remote PC, but that remote user account is a local admin on the remote machine, you will be logged in with the local context on the remote PC and be an administrator on that remote PC.